# How to reduce the memory spike while zooming pdf PDFKIT?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-pdfkit

I'm working on pdf ink annotation using apples PDFKit, when I do good amount of annotations and start zooming the pdf page, I notice spike in memory usage and as a result the pdf page hangs while zooming.
I checked several answers and yet no solution found, I'm using bezier path for bounds and yet no luck.

```
PDFAnnotation(bounds: path.bounds, forType: .ink, withProperties: nil)
```